# Retrieving salesforce data into triggered email sent

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

I am trying to send a triggered email send which has a link that leads to a cloudpage. I need some salesforce data within the link for it to work.

```
    %%[
VAR @futureDate, @today, @url, @subRecordId, @subLanguage, @subscription, @subscriptionRow, @mySObject, @rowCount
SET @today = Now(1) 
SET @futureDate = DateAdd(@today, 90, "D")

Set @mySObject = AttributeValue("SObject")
SET @subRecordId = AttributeValue("RecordId")

SET @subscription = (SObject,"MAG_Language__c","Id", "=", @subRecordId)
SET @rowCount = rowCount(@subscription)

IF @rowCount > 0 THEN

    SET @subscriptionRow = Row(@subscription, 1)
    SET @subLanguage = FIELD(@subscriptionRow, "MAG_Language__c")

ENDIF

set @url_yes = Concat("https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/0tifupaskin?sk=%%@subRecordId%%&ln=%%@subLanguage%%&expiry=",Format(@futureDate,"yyyy-MM-dd"))
set @url_no = Concat("https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/i25beezqh3g?sk=%%@subRecordId%%&ln=%%@subLanguage%%&expiry=",Format(@futureDate,"yyyy-MM-dd"))
]%%
```

I built the below by looking through StackExchange but it's not working. Also the triggered send doesn't like it as it won't activate with this in the email. Also I don't understand the SObject part. Do I replace SObject with the name of the custom object the triggered send is sending from? Any help will be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the RetrieveSalesforceObjects command, and you're terminating your AMPScript in your querystring. See below for the recommended changes.

```
    %%[
VAR @futureDate, @today, @url, @subRecordId, @subLanguage, @subscription, @subscriptionRow, @mySObject, @rowCount
SET @today = Now(1) 
SET @futureDate = DateAdd(@today, 90, "D")
SET @formattedDate = Format(@futureDate,"yyyy-MM-dd")

Set @mySObject = AttributeValue("SObject")
SET @subRecordId = AttributeValue("RecordId")

SET @subscription = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(@mySObject,"MAG_Language__c","Id", "=", @subRecordId)
SET @rowCount = rowCount(@subscription)

IF @rowCount > 0 THEN

    SET @subscriptionRow = Row(@subscription, 1)
    SET @subLanguage = FIELD(@subscriptionRow, "MAG_Language__c")

ENDIF

set @url_yes = Concat("https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/0tifupaskin?sk=",@subRecordId,"&ln=",@subLanguage,"&expiry=",@formattedDate)
set @url_no = Concat("https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/i25beezqh3g?sk=",@subRecordId,"&ln=",@subLanguage,"&expiry=",@formattedDate)
]%%
```